# how to select files created/modified on a particular date in linux folder?

Tags: bash, terminal

in a linux folder , ls -al gives me the following. If i want to select/copy or delelte files created or modified on a certain date , how can i do that from the terminal?

```
$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 1 usr 197609    0 Jun  5  2020  ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 usr 197609    0 Jun 29 11:05  ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197609 1337 Jul  5  2020 'Dump202007049.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197609 6020 Jul  5  2020  Dump202007050.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197609 6020 Jul  6  2020  Dump202007051.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 197609 6020 Jul  7  2020  Dump202007052.sql
```

Comment: If you know how many days ago the date you're interested in is, using `zsh` instead of `bash` will let you apply a filter directly to a glob pattern: `*(m6)` or `*(#qm6)` depending on settings for files modified 6 days ago. More information at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `find` command, particular the `-atime` and `-mtime` arguments.

Comment: I suggest to delete `-atime` (last access).